# Serial COM RS-485 TO SQL DATABASE

Tags: html, sql

We are a bachelor group, working on a project where we need to get the data from our [Moxa converter](http://www.moxa.com) to a SQL database.

We are right now working with SMA, Kamstrup and Fronius component Solar panel, windmill etc.

We wants to retrieve data from those components so we can make a display (HMI) for our website, so we can illustrate how much power etc it provides at the science center.

Right now we have managed to retrieve the data from the holding registers,
but [CAS modbus scanner](http://www.chipkin.com/products/software/modbus.../cas-modbus-scanner/) can't put the data into a website.

So I wonder if someone here have any experience in how I can retrieve those data through REAL Serial and get it into a database, where I can use the data on a website?

Comment: Some examples and a more specific question would be nice.

Comment: What is a "bachelor group"?

Comment: You are probably going to need an application to translate the serial data from your disparate components into data that you can use, and then upload that data into a SQL database.  That's a rather hefty task for a stack overflow answer.

Comment: @FelipeSulser  

The Solar panel produce power. I want to maybe use the data to make a display of a graph on a website for example? Maybe use the data for something else, like making some graphics to show the data?

Comment: @AbeMiessler A bachelor group is a group that works with a project given by school, you have to pass it to get a bachelor degree in computer engineering.

Comment: Ahh interesting - thanks!

Comment: @Kateract You are right about that, well... Well, I was just trying to check if any had any opinions for which software it would be good to complete this task :D

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Modbus datalogger. Chipkin provides [several](http://www.chipkin.com/products/data-loggers/modbus-loggers/) that can be bought either as hardware devices or software only; but they're not free.

Comment: We are in contact with Chicken right now!  I hope they will offer us a good solution so we can complete our task! :)

We are still open for more suggestions, if there´s any!

Comment: It seems like it wasn't a option since it was way to expensive... it cost 875$ for a license...